# How to pass view from Child Component to Parent in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am having a Parent Component(Container) where am displaying products in a table, on clicking header cells, am calling a Modal Window which is the Child Component.

On cliking submit in Modal Window, I should be able to pass a view from Child to Parent(i.e from Modal to Container), replace the table view in the Container with the view that is passed from Modal(child). As of now, only the console.log in child is printed but the result is not getting rendered. I am not sure how to pass the view from child, back to parent. Can any one help me please.

Here is the code -

Container (Parent) :

```
render(){
        ......
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.onButtonClick} text="Compare" 
                isDisabled={this.state.isDisabled} style={btnstyle}/> 
                <Button onClick={this.onClearClick} text="Clear" />
                <br />
                <br />
                //The below line is the actual view. I need to replace this view with the view that is passed from Modal
                {!this.state.activeFilter ? this.fullList() : this.compareView()}
                <br />
                <MyModal show={this.state.show} handleClose={this.handleClose}
                 body={this.state.checkboxInputValue==="Part Number" ? allPartNumbers : allProductLines} 
                 title={this.state.checkboxInputValue} submit={this.onButtonClick}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Modal (Child) :

```
//The view returned in this method should be passed to Parent(Container) and displayed there
onSubmit = (event) => {
    //this.props.handleClose
    //event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ selected: [] });
    this.props.handleClose();
    const data = this.state.data;
    const selectedData = this.state.selected;
    console.log("selectedData -- "+selectedData)

    let filterredData = data.filter(row =>
        selectedData.includes(row.PartNumber)
    );
    this.setState({ data: filterredData });

    const filteredPartNumbers = this.state.data.map(partnumbers =>partnumbers.PartNumber);
    const filteredProductLines = this.state.data.map(productlines =>productlines.productline);
    const filteredProductImages = this.state.data.map(productimages =>productimages.url);

    return (

        <div>
            <table id="compare-results-table" className="table vertical table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Part Number</th>
                        {filteredPartNumbers.map(k => <td key={k}>{k}</td>)}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product Line</th>
                        {filteredProductLines.map(k => <td key={k}>{k}</td>)}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product Image</th>
                        {filteredProductImages.map(k => <td key={k}><Image src={k} /></td>)}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
};

render(){
   // console.log("inmodal =="+this.props.allPartNumbers)
    return(
        <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.handleClose}>
            .....
            <Modal.Footer>
                <button variant="secondary" onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} >Submit</button>
                .....
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}`enter code here`
```

Full code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/my3x6zoz6y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should have a look if filterredData is set correctly and fullList() is rendered subsequently. This should easily be possible by logging to the console.

Comment: please give a sample to make sense.

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad I have mentioned that full code is here - Full code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/my3x6zoz6y. When clicking on the checkbox - Part Number or Product Line, a Modal window is opened. Once the options within the  modal body are checked and hit on submit, the xpectation is that the tabular markup written in the return function of "onSubmit" in MyModal.js should display.

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad I have modified my question and made it more elaborate. Please take a look